# eBay API - get notification when a product has been sold

Tags: product, ebay-api

I have an ecommerce and eBay store, in my ecommerce-DB there are the same products of the store, classic solution, but i want to know if there is a way to know, in real time, when a product has been sold through a notification, or kind stuff? Because i must send a request on eBay, every time someone visit my website, to know which product are still in sale. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [eBay Platform Notification API](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/platform-notifications-landing.html) can be used for this.

#### EDIT

I haven't used this but from what I gather eBay sends a SOAP response message to the URL you supply.

So it would be like any other request that you would receive. Then you can parse the XML of the soap response and do whatever you want with it.

Probably the easiest way to get an idea of what it is doing is to set up a notification and a script to dump the POST data to a file so you could see what it is doing.

Comment: Thank you, man! i think that i have VPS, at least, for use this service?

Comment: I think eBay just POSTs a notification to a url you supply so any type of hosting should work.

Comment: i'm sorry, how can i get this object XML through an url (on my server)?

Comment: should i have a daemon with keep-alive connection?

Comment: No you don't need to. The request will run like any normal request made from a browser.

Comment: Like a polling? I need an alert in exacly moment that a product have been sold

Comment: I don't know what type of delay there is when eBay sends notifications but I wouldn't think it would be very long. The problem with polling is the API call restrictions. About 500,000 per day at a basic level? And to get instant notifications you would have to have a high polling frequency. For a large application you could easily reach that limit.

Comment: yes, for this i meant keep-alive connection, or use of socket to have an instant message when product has been sold on my Ebay store. Need something an instant messaging technology.

Comment: I don't think that eBay has anything like that.

Comment: i think eBay just send those messages, but i must to able to receive it, maybe with socket...

Comment: i discover that communication work with SOAP API, and there is an implementation made from eBay

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867718/php-ebay-api-platformnotifications

but i don't understand where and how implement my code. Can you help me? :)